# Running Junit Tests from Main in Maven with Cucumber

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, cucumber

I have a simple test runner class in a sub directory: src/test/java

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
//@Feature("my/package/**/*.feature")
@CucumberOptions(

  features= {"src/test/java/multiTest/Login_Logout.feature"}
, glue={"stepDefs"}
, monochrome = true
, plugin = {"pretty"}
)

public class TestRunner {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    
    System.out.println("This is a test");
    JUnitCore.main("multiTest.TestRunner");    
}
}
```

From my main file: src/main/java I would like to call this TestRunner class. Eventually this will be configured to take user input from the main thread and pass it into the testing thread. However the last line in this class is throwing compilation errors.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("QA for EDI");
    // Setting the width and height of frame
    frame.setSize(500, 450);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    /* Creating panel. This is same as a div tag in HTML
     * We can create several panels and add them to specific 
     * positions in a JFrame. Inside panels we can add text 
     * fields, buttons and other components.
     */
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();    
    // adding panel to frame
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    TestRunner.run(TestRunner.class);
}
```

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

`TestRunner` does not have a static run() method thus you get the error. The run() belongs to the Thread class.

What are you trying to achieve by this setup? If you want to pass any data put it in the feature file directly. That is the whole point of scenarios in Cucumber. Put in all the different things you want to test as separate scenarios.

Anyways to use the `TestRunner` class to do anything Cucumber specific you need to use the Cucumber TestRunner class which is mentioned in the `RunWith` annotation. And the main method in the `TestRunner` will never be called by Cucumber.

Comment: I'm trying to make this program portable so that the test can run through a GUI without anyone touching the code. Others will write and specify the feature files so my program will just be the step library and test runner.

Comment: The idea is to call the main method from the GUI and then within the main JUnitCore.main("multiTest.TestRunner");   will call the TestRunner again and hit the Cucumber annotation.

Comment: What kind of inputs will the user provide?

Comment: Browser type, feature files, and user credentials.

Comment: Have a look at CLI runner for cucumber-jvm.

Comment: Could you perhaps be more specific?